# posgresql: select lag values in one column for each distinct value in other column ordered by date

Tags: postgresql, date, select, subquery, window-functions

I have the following table t_table:

```
   t_date   |           t_sec           |     t_gross
------------+---------------------------+------------------
 2020-04-30 | 09.620.860/0001-00        | 85434.1700000001
 2020-04-30 | 09.636.393/0001-07        |         385465.4
 2020-04-30 | 09.720.710/0001-60        | 87555.7622531644
 2020-04-30 | 10.474.514/0001-32        |     756.34924792
 2020-04-30 | 14.188.162/0001-00        | 83565.6134686463
 2020-05-29 | 09.620.860/0001-00        |         85518.24
 2020-05-29 | 09.636.393/0001-07        |        416453.08
 2020-05-29 | 09.720.710/0001-60        |   87823.13921208
 2020-05-29 | 10.474.514/0001-32        |     756.34924792
 2020-05-29 | 14.188.162/0001-00        |   84058.44715029
```

I want to query t_gross values for 2020-05-29 and its corresponding one month-lagged t_gross value for each t_sec. Using the following select statement:

```
SELECT 
    t_sec, 
    t_date, 
    t_gross, 
    LAG(t_date,1) OVER (ORDER BY t_date), 
    LAG(t_gross,1) OVER (ORDER BY t_date) 
FROM t_table 
WHERE t_date = '2020-05-29';
```

And get the following result:

```
           t_sec           |   t_date   |     t_gross      |    lag     |       lag
---------------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------
 09.620.860/0001-00        | 2020-05-29 |         85518.24 | 2020-04-30 | 83565.6134686463
 09.636.393/0001-07        | 2020-05-29 |        416453.08 | 2020-05-29 |         85518.24
 09.720.710/0001-60        | 2020-05-29 |   87823.13921208 | 2020-05-29 |        416453.08
 10.474.514/0001-32        | 2020-05-29 |     756.34924792 | 2020-05-29 |   87823.13921208
 14.188.162/0001-00        | 2020-05-29 |   84058.44715029 | 2020-05-29 |     756.34924792
```

I am not obtaining the one-month-lag t_gross for each t_sec, but just the lag t_gross value ordered by date. How can I get the lag t_gross for each corresponding t_sec, for example 85434.1700000001 should be the lag t_gross for t_sec 09.620.860/0001-00, not 83565.6134686463. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `PARTITION BY` clause to separate rows by `t_sec`:

```
LAG(t_date)  OVER (PARTITION BY t_sec ORDER BY t_date), 
LAG(t_gross) OVER (PARTITION BY t_sec ORDER BY t_date)
```

Side note: `1` is the default value of the second argument to `lag()`, so you can just omitt it here.

Comment: Thank you BMG. If I include date '2020-05-29' in the WHERE clause I get NULL in the LAG columns. If I drop the WHERE clause I get the results I want for all dates. How I get values only for '2020-05-29'?

Comment: @MGarcia: you would typically filter in an outer query: `select * from (select ..., lag()... from ...) t where  t_date = '2020-05-29'`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!